# Does PDCurses and ncurses have the same syntax?

Tags: syntax, ncurses, pdcurses

I'm building a game with ncurses in Linux.

Can I "copy/paste" the code into Microsoft Visual Studio (properly set for PDCurses) and everything will run OK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is the same, but the question doesn't deal with **syntax**

They are "largely compatible", but each has features not found in the other.  Offhand (no one's made a complete comparison):

- PDCurses doesn't have a low-level ([terminfo](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html) or [termcap](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html)) interface
- PDCurses has explicit definitions for alt/control keys, e.g.,

```
    #define CTL_LEFT      0x1bb  /* Control-Left-Arrow */
    #define CTL_RIGHT     0x1bc
    #define CTL_PGUP      0x1bd
    #define CTL_PGDN      0x1be
    #define CTL_HOME      0x1bf
    #define CTL_END       0x1c0
```

With ncurses, those would be [user-defined capabilities](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_N_C_U_R_S_E_S__U_S_E_R-_D_E_F_I_N_A_B_L_E__C_A_P_A_B_I_L_I_T_I_E_S).  The terminal description would have capabilities for the *control* cursor keys such as **`kDN5` (control down-arrow) and the application find these at runtime using `tigetstr` (to get the values) and [`key_defined`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/key_defined.3x.html) to find the coding used by ncurses.  The names are based on [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-PC-Style-Function-Keys), but could include other terminals (most of the ones aside from rxvt that you'll find copy xterm).  Sounds cumbersome, but both ncurses/PDCurses took their own path in extending X/Open Curses.

- [`resize_term`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h3-resize_term) is different (in ncurses it responds to the window size changes, while PDCurses allows changing the window size).
- programs written to use Unicode values (or which assume that strings are UTF-8) probably will not port without some effort.